# No entity manager defined for class DateTime

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I have started using the `Sonata Admin` bundle and I was following the example on how to map an entity with the bundle to create an administrative interface.

I created an entity called `Post` and this is the configuration yml file:

```
Emiliano\PostsBundle\Entity\Post:
type: entity
table: null
repositoryClass: Emiliano\PostsBundle\Entity\PostRepository
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    title:
        type: string
        column: Title
        lenght: 100
    published:
        type: boolean
        column: Published
    publishingDate:
        type: datetime
        column: Publishing_Date
        nullable: TRUE
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Then in my `Admin` class I have the `configureFormFields` method:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {
    $formMapper->add('title', 'text')
       ->add('published', 'checkbox', array('required' => false))
       ->add('publishingDate', 'sonata_type_model_hidden');
}
```

I found the `sonata_type_model_hidden` on the sonata admin [documentation](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/form_types.html). What I would like to achieve is to programmatically handle the publishing date (e.g. set the date only if the checkbox `published` is checked) hiding the implementation to the user.

Everything works fine for create, delete and read, when it comes to modify an entity I get this message in the stacktrace:

```
No entity manager defined for class DateTime
In sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle/Sonata/DoctrineORMAdminBundle/Model/ModelManager.php at line 214
```

If I show the field everything works fine, I tried also to use:

```
->add('publishingDate', 'hidden');
```

without success.

What is exactly the problem here? Is it because `Sonata Admin` tries to fill a form with the entity values and for publishingDate there's a `DateTime` while in the form specification I wrote a `sonata_type_model_hidden`? If so, how can I circumvent this?

Comment: So what is in line 214 in ModelManager?  I'm guessing that you might be using DateTime instead of \DateTime.  Pure speculation.

Comment: `$em = $this->registry->getManagerForClass($class);` and I am using \DateTime.

Comment: Then check your code because I'm pretty sure you have $class = 'DateTime' and there certainly would not be a $em for it.

Comment: What I don't actually understand is whether this is a sonata admin bug or something I overlooked, I don't create the form, the bundle maps my entity creating an administrative interface and checks the `configureFormFields` that I wrote and nowhere I am passing a `DateTime` object. Anyway I checked the `$class` variable from my previous comment and it's `DateTime`, I tried to change it to `\DateTime` without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sonata_type_model_hidden` isn't just `hidden` field genereator, according to documentation:

> `sonata_type_model_hidden` will use an instance of ModelHiddenType to render hidden field. The value of hidden field is identifier of related entity.

If I understand your problem, You want to set publishing date only when field `published` == true

You could use entity `preSave/preUpdate` lifecycle callback for eaxmple

```
public function preSave() 
{
     /**
      * Check if item is published
      */
     if($this->getPublished()) {
         $this->setPublishingDate(new \DateTime());
     } else {
         $this->setPublishingDate(null);
     }
}
```

and remove `publishingDate` field from SonataAdmin form.

Comment: I was already using the preSave/preUpdate hooks, I ended up removing the fields form the form since they were useless, still why this error happens intrigues me.